# JQuery Carousel multiple instances on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I am trying to use a third-party jQuery Carousel plugin in a project at work (don't know which plugin it is though). The problem is that when I use multiple instances of the same plugin on the same page only one of the instances updates. I think this issue is with how my instances are setup. I have constructed a jsFiddle at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5HVqa/).

The carousel is attached by the .carousel class and all instances are initiated by the method shown below:

```
// Enable carousel
$.each($('.carousel'), function (i) {
    $(this).carousel(this.id);
});
```

Unlike in my local code, in the JsFiddle only one of the carousels works. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly there is an error when your js runs.  If you look in your browser dev tools of choice you should see

> TypeError: properties.slider.swipe is not a function

Once commented out the js will run correctly but if you click any of the next and previous buttons only the bottom slider will run.  This is because they use the same instance of the `var` `properties`.

I would suggest looking at creating a jQuery widget with your existing code, it is fairly straight forward to do.  By doing this you can have several instances of the same widget running on a page together.

[Coding your first jQuery ui plugin](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/coding-your-first-jquery-ui-plugin/)

Comment: Thanks Colin. I can't believe I missed the missing swipe function :) I am going to give your solution a try.

Comment: Thank you very much Colin. As you said it wasn't too difficult to implement my existing code as a jQuery UI Widget.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fix the entire plug-in, it's much easier to tell you that after the plug-in is initialized, the plug-in code breaks when it attempts to add touch events.

```
// Add touch events
properties.slider.swipe(function (event) {
    if (event.swipeDirection == 'left') {
       methods.next();
   } else if (event.swipeDirection == 'right') {
       methods.previous();
   }
});
// Throws: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'swipe'
```

[Comment out the plug-in code's touch events](http://jsfiddle.net/5HVqa/7/), and it no longer breaks. 
However, because of how the plug-in is created, it can only handle one carousel at a time since it overwrites the last one that was defined.

[Try a different, widely-used, and responsive JS slider that supports touch events.](http://www.slidesjs.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Josh. I can't believe I missed the missing swipe function :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have created Carousel without using any third party plugin.If you want please refer

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431165/jquery-carousel-with-fading-text)

Hope its helps you.