# Carousel plugin/code with removable/addable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I want to implement a kind of horizontal carousel effect on a couple of images such that each image can be dragged out of the carousel or dragged back into it conversely and the carousel effect still takes place. Is there any JavaScript/jQuery plugin out there that can help me achieve this kind of effect?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have created carousel by own to my project.

Please visit to given link.

[**Whole Code Link for Carousel**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431165/jquery-carousel-with-fading-text)

Hope it helps you.